# Does $\sum\limits_{x=1}^\infty\sin(x)$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, trigonometric-series

I received a task to find out whether the following series converges:

$$\sum_{x=1}^\infty\sin(x)$$

On first look it seems simple, but as I keep thinking about it, there's not a single lemma or criterion that I can use to tackle the problem.

D'alembert ? Doesn't work: The following is meaningless IMHO: $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}{}\frac{\sin(x+1)}{\sin(x)}$

That series isn't monotonic... you can't understand the rules for when will a member of the series be negative or positive.

All I know is that $\sin(x)$ is blocked between (-1) and 1.
Though it's easy to see that $ \sum\limits_{x=1}^\infty\lvert\sin(x) \rvert$ diverges.

May I use [Leibniz formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80) for $\pi$ in order to construct  2 subseries:

- One that shows that $\sin(x)$ converges to the limit 1
- Another one that shows that $\sin(x)$ converges to the limit 0

And we know that a series can't converge to 2 different numbers, hence it diverges?

Comment: Sorry but would you guys please add a simple proof for why $\sin(x)$ diverges? I'm not (yet) a mathematician that can understand the proof of "partial sums"...

Comment: Dear Dor, convergence or divergence of the series is, really, a claim about the sequence of partial sums of the series. It is going to be essentially impossible to explain why the series does not converge without making use of its partial sums!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I know, but someone added a proof of partial sums which includes the expression $e^{i(n-1)/2}$, and I don't understand the meaning of that... How do I use it to prove the divergence of $\sin(x)$? It's not as clear to me as it is clear to you...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The sequence $(\sin n)$ doesn't converge to $0$ so the given series is divergent.

Comment: In which sentence/lemma did you use in order to figure it out?

Comment: I doubt there's a name for this; the partial sums aren't a Cauchy sequence if the summands don't converge to $0$. Any convergent sequence is Cauchy.

Comment: If the series $\sum u_n$ converges then its partial sum $S_n$ is convergent sequence and then $u_n=S_n-S_{n-1}$ converges to $0$. Now use the contrapositive.

Comment: It's pretty easy to show that $\sin n$ cannot converge to zero. If $\sin n$ is close enough to zero, then $\sin (n+1)$ is close to $\pm \sin 1$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, but you can't indicate about the convergence of a series by its tail.

Comment: In some books this is called the Divergence test.

Comment: @Dor just to make sure we're on the same page, that's absolutely true BUT the statement "$\sum a_n$ converges $\implies$ $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$" is still always true. Its contrapositive is "$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n\neq 0$ $\implies$ $\sum a_n$ does not converge", which is the statement needed to prove the theorem.

Comment: "The contrapositive is a mathematician's best friend. Or rather, anyone whose best friend isn't the contrapositive, isn't a mathematician."

Answer (score 11):

**Hint:** The partial sums  have an explicit form, because there are the imaginary part of some geometric series.

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n e^{ik} = \frac {1-e^{in}}{1-e^i}
= \frac {e^{-in/2}-e^{in/2}}{e^{-i/2}-e^{i/2}} \frac{e^{in/2}}{e^{i/2}}
= \frac{\sin \frac n2}{\sin \frac 12} e^{i(n-1)/2}
$$
so the $n$th partial sum is
$$
\frac{1}{\sin \frac 12} \sin \frac n2\sin{\frac{n-1}2}
= \frac{1}{2\sin \frac 12} \left(\cos \frac 12 - \cos \frac{2n-1}4\right)
$$

From this, you can explicitly see what values are taken by these partial sums.

Comment: You are thus left with showing that $\cos(2n-1)/4$ does no converge, which is almost equivalent to the original problem :-)

Comment: well, there is *some* difference between the convergence of $U_n$ and the convergence of $\sum U_n$

Comment: Apparently the response side-steps the issue about the convergence of the sum. So why does it merit +7 points?

Comment: @M.Wind well, you can downvote it. It's not like I care about your particular opinion.

Comment: Downvoting your asnswer would be petty.

Answer (score 2):

If $\sin(n) \to 0$, then $|\cos(n)| \to 1$, so $\sum \cos(n)$ diverges, but $\sin(n+1)= \sin(n)\cos(1) + \cos(n)\sin(1)$, so $\sum \sin(1) \cos(n) = \sum \sin(n+1) - \sum \cos(1)\sin(n)$.

Comment: Obviously your comment is mathematically sound. It is less clear what the purpose is. The formula you present can be seen as a first step to rearrange terms in the infinite sum. But then what? Are you suggesting that rearranging terms in this way leads to cancellation of terms in the sum or even convergence? If that is not the case, what it is that you want to say?

Comment: @M.Wind, this answer very clearly proposes a (very nice!) way to answer the question, which is, as you know, «does the series converge?» Quinn is not proposing any rearrangement of anything.

Comment: Sorry, but it is not clear to me! And presumably also not helpful for the OP. I don't like it when experts post one formula without comment, thereby implicitly hinting at something. It suggests to me they don't have the guts to state explicitly what they mean.

Comment: @M.Wind You must meditate on this answer until it becomes clear. Then you shall be enlightened.